# Azure File Share over VPN

Tags: azure, network-share, file-sharing, azure-networking

I currently have a folder inside a VM in Azure that is shared among several users using SMB and connecting using a VPN to this VM and them mounting the virtual folder on Windows (like \10.0.0.1\folder).

Now, as I don't want to maintain this server 24/7, I transferred those files to a Azure File Share.

Problem is: I can't connect to the Azure File Share as my company blocks port 445 to public IPs.

So, I need a way to access Azure File Share by some VPN. Is there any way I can connect my storage account to a virtual network and has its private IP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it an option to set the firewall to allow outbound 445 connections just to the Azure IP ranges?

Comment: @ToddWilcox, unfortunately, this is not an option.

Comment: No. You can integrate with the Virtual Network, but that's mainly to allow/block traffic from external traffic. You can't generate an IP address to access the storage account.

Answer (score 1):

> So, I need a way to access Azure File Share by some VPN.

Yes, you could.

You could setup Windows Azure (Server 2012) as an SSTP and L2TP VPN Provider, your client PC connects to this VPN. I test it in my lab, it works for me. I could mount file share even though ISP block 445 Port. More information about how to setup Azure Windows as a VPN provider, please refer to the [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/notime/2013/06/01/how-to-setup-windows-azure-server-2012-as-an-sstp-and-l2tp-vpn-provider/).

Also, you could refer to this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af1a8967-aa57-483d-afbd-0059acf02c81/tunneling-to-azure-storage-file-services?forum=windowsazuredata) which is the same with you.